# Arithmetic calculation in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I'm a beginner in bash scripting. As i was testing myself i came across this question. **Get an integer as input from the user, multiply it by 5, and prints whether the result is greater than 14.** 
My script is somewhat around this

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Insert an Integer"
read input
echo $((input*5))
num1 =$((input*5))
num2 =14
if [ $num1 \> $b ];
then 
    echo "a is greater than b";
else
    echo "b is greater than a";
fi;
```

Can i get some help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(()) are the brackets to be used for all arithmetic operations, including tests, so you could do:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Enter an integer: " input

echo "You entered: $input"

(( num1 = input * 5 ))

echo "$input multiplied by 5 is $num1"

num2=14

if (( num1 > num2 ))
then
  echo "$input multiplied by 5 is greater than 14"
else
  echo "$input multiplied by 5 is NOT greater than 14"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

I see a few problems here.  Where did `$b` suddenly come from?
What is a and b?  Why do echo statements talk about `a` & `b`?

You also have some obvious syntax errors, which you'll see if you run that script.

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Enter an Integer"
read input
echo "You entered: $input"
num1=$((input*5))
echo "$input multiplied by 5 is $num1" 
num2=14
if [ $num1 -gt  $num2 ];
then 
        echo "$input multiplied by 5 is greater than 14"
    else
        echo "$input multiplied by 5 is NOT greater than 14"
fi
```